# Executing a file with one command per line with xargs

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, xargs

I have a file which consists of a series of commands, one per line. For example:

`./run_test_1.sh fileA
./run_test_1.sh fileB
./run_test_2.sh fileC`

I want to run these in parallel, using xargs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
printf "%s\0" $(cat afile) | xargs -0 -P 3 -I xxx bash -c xxx
```

`xargs` is going to run 3 commands from `afile` in parallel.

Special chars in the commands or their options will break this solution.

### ----

The version below seems safe, but then all commands in `afile` are executed in sequence:

```
printf "%s\0" "$(cat afile)" | xargs -0 -P 3 -I xxx bash -c xxx
```

The `-P 3` is useless here.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. I'm not sure why I was having trouble, I thought I tried that!

This is only for scripts I write myself, so I'll be sure not to use any special characters.

Comment: @ChrisJefferson the command has just been updated with a safer version

Comment: Doesn't this send the entire file to `xargs` as one "line"? How would it parallelize that? Ah. I see the original "worked" but the edit is wrong.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes. So this `printf "%s\0" "$(cat afile)"` sends the whole file. It seems safe in the test, **but** there is no more parallel execution (`-P 3` is useless). If the **"** are removed around `$(cat afile)` then there is parallelism **AND** special chars in the commands are going to break it.

Comment: Right. I don't believe what the OP wants is actually doable in a safe manner. Not for all possible line contents. ... Well, it might be doable in a safe way (assuming the initial commands are written safely) with something like `while IFS= read -r line; do bash -c "$line"; done < file` or similar but I'd have to think about it more (or look up other answers about it).

Comment: A fully safe version would be great (where my lines could contain redirections for example) -- this would allow me to fully replace my personal uses of gnu parallel (which I need to stop using) with just xargs.